# Runnable war with jetty+guice

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, guice-servlet, code-separation

This is a question about better separating the code for *embedding jetty* from the code for *wiring up servlets*.

I am trying to adapt [this sample code](https://github.com/teamlazerbeez/simple-web-stack) such that I will be getting a runnable war, i.e. a war file that I can drop into an existing Jetty container, or run standalone using a command like `java -jar webapp-runnable.war`.
The sample code belongs to these two blog posts: [No.1](http://blog.palominolabs.com/2011/08/15/a-simple-java-web-stack-with-guice-jetty-jersey-and-jackson/), [No.2](http://blog.palominolabs.com/2012/03/31/extending-the-simple-javajettyguicejerseyjackson-web-stack-with-automatic-jersey-resource-method-metrics/).

I followed the [GuiceServlet manual](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule) and created a `web.xml` and `GuiceServletContextListener` (see below), but they don't seem to get me very far with `mvn jetty:run`; When I try to run `mvn jetty:run`, I get the following error:

```
[main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging to Logger[org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] via org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@3cceafcb{/,file:/[...]/src/main/webapp/,STARTING}{file:/[...]/src/main/webapp/}
com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:||1) Explicit bindings are required and com.google.inject.servlet.InternalServletModule$BackwardsCompatibleServletContextProvider is not explicitly bound.|  while locating com.google.inject.servlet.InternalServletModule$BackwardsCompatibleServletContextProvider||1 error
    at [stack strace clipped]
```

***Here's my code.*** As mentioned before, I started with [this repo on github](https://github.com/teamlazerbeez/simple-web-stack).

**1)** I extracted the anonymous inner class of type AbstractModule from [`com.teamlazerbeez.http.HttpServerMain`](https://github.com/teamlazerbeez/simple-web-stack/blob/master/src/main/java/com/teamlazerbeez/http/HttpServerMain.java) and put it into a new class `com.teamlazerbeez.http.HttpServerModule`. This class is now instantiated when creating the Guice Injector [in `HttpServerMain` (l36)](https://github.com/teamlazerbeez/simple-web-stack/blob/master/src/main/java/com/teamlazerbeez/http/HttpServerMain.java#L36).

**2)** My `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    metadata-complete="false"
    version="3.0">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.teamlazerbeez.http.GuiceServletConfig</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

**3)** My `com.teamlazerbeez.http.GuiceServletConfig`:

```
public class GuiceServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        //I know this code not come close to doing what I want, but I just don't know where to start
        return Guice.createInjector(new HttpServerModule());
    }

}
```

**My question:** How can I refactor the `HttpServerMain` `main` method and `HttpServerModule` in such a way that the setup process described by them becomes usable to my `GuiceServletConfig`? And what must `GuiceServletConfig` look like for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never got a war working as jar, so I always go for one of the two solutions. However, when using a war, its not hard to setup a embedded Jetty server that works in your IDE. To do that you can use a `WebAppContext` to set it up using a `web.xml`. See [this documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html) for an example. From there, everything should work as advocated on the Guice site.

However, this will not create a runnable war (like `java -jar yourapp.war`) because jars have a different internal layout. However, if you want to you can use the [jetty-runner](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.eclipse.jetty%7Cjetty-runner%7C9.1.2.v20140210%7Cjar) to fix this using `java -jar jetty-runner.jar yourapp.war`.

Answer (score 1):

I took [@Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/679913/alex)'s [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21728655/1296709) and forget about creating a standalone-runnable `war`, and instead focused on creating just a `war` that does most of the wiring up in a guice [ServletModule](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule).

For this purpose, I changed my `HttpServerModule` to extend a `ServletModule` (instead of `AbstractModule`) and put most of the `HttpServerMain.main()` logic in its `configureServlets()` method:

```
public class HttpServerModule extends ServletModule {
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        MetricRegistry metricRegistry = new MetricRegistry();
        bind(MetricRegistry.class).toInstance(metricRegistry);

        install(new SandwichModule());
        install(new JerseyMetricsModule());

        JmxReporter reporter = JmxReporter.forRegistry(metricRegistry).build();
        reporter.start();
    }
}
```

You'll notice that some of the `HttpServerMain.main()` logic does not appear in java code any more now. This is because the `web.xml` takes care of these things now.

My `web.xml` and `GuiceServletConfig` remain unchanged, and I can now run this using the `mvn jetty:run command`. The HttpServerMain can now be deleted, as it does not do anything useful any more.